# VLC MediaPlayer Python Lood video

Tags: python, loops, media-player, vlc

I am programming video loop with VLC MediaPlayer, however when video is finished, I have some    time that video stop and replay (the video closes and reopens).

I am using this code:

```py
    def onEnd(event):
       global doTrashCode
       if event.type == vlc.EventType.MediaPlayerEndReached:
          doTrashCode = True

    def function():
       video_inicio = vlc.MediaPlayer(source_inicio)
       video_inicio.set_fullscreen(True)
       em = video_inicio.event_manager()
       em.event_attach(vlc.EventType.MediaPlayerEndReached, onEnd)
      video_inicio.play()
    
      while 1:
          if(doTrashCode):
             video_inicio.set_media(video_inicio.get_media()) 
             time.sleep(0.5)
             video_inicio.play()
             doTrashCode = False
     ...
```

Comment: maybe you should use `video_inicio.set_position(0)` to move to the beginnig of video - without using `set_media()`, `play()`, `time.sleep()`, etc,

Comment: It isn't working, I was thinking this, but it is not working because reference video is lost when it is finished

Comment: the only idea - use `set_position(0)` little before end of video - but this can make problem to run `set_position` in correct moment.

Comment: i have made it, but bucle video have a a little stop when set_position(0)

Comment: I tested it on small file and I didn't see this problem. But maybe it need to use something different - ie. cv2.VideoCapture(file) to read frame by frame. But it needs also to create window to display it - so it need more work.

Comment: i will try it! Thanks!